# How to process NonBlocking with Smallrye messaging and reactive http client?

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-rest-client, smallrye-reactive-messaging

I have the following code.

```
@Incoming("my-topic")
void process(String someEvent) {
     String someResponse = assuminglyRealFastReactiveClientCall();
}
```

The above code throws a blocking thread exception. Which is corrected with `@Blocking`.

```
@Incoming("my-topic")
@Blocking
void process(String someEvent) {
     String someResponse = assuminglyRealFastReactiveClientCall();
}
```

If I switch `String assuminglyRealFastReactiveClientCall()` to `Uni<String> assuminglyRealFastReactiveClientCall()`

I'm guessing the consumer method has to switch to manual ack strategy and the message needs to be acked/nacked based on the result of the subscribe, so?

```
@Incoming("my-topic")
void process(Message<String> someEvent) {
     assuminglyRealFastReactiveClientCall()
                .subscribe().with(s -> {
                    System.out.println("Response: " + s);
                    event.ack();
                }, t -> event.nack(t));

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Incoming("my-topic")
    Uni<Void> process(Message<String> someEvent) {
        return assuminglyRealFastReactiveClientCall()
                .invoke(this::handleResponse)
                .chain(response -> Uni.createFrom().completionStage(someEvent.ack()));

    }

    private void handleResponse(String response) {
        // Do something with the response
    }
```

The paragraph [Consuming Messages](https://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.4/model/model.html#consuming-messageshttps://smallrye.io/smallrye-reactive-messaging/smallrye-reactive-messaging/3.4/model/model.html#consuming-messages) in the Smallrye Reactive messaging documentation has many more examples.